# How to handle Time index with using groupby in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, resampling

I have a csv file with several variables. 
Among the variables, Date and time is included separately.
Following image is the form of my data:

```
  Date         Time       Axis1     Axis2    Axis3
   .             .         .          .       .
   .             .         .          .       .
2017-10-15    13:40:00     20         0       40
2017-10-15    13:40:10     40         10      100
2017-10-15    13:40:20     50         0       0
2017-10-15    13:40:30     10         10      60
2017-10-15    13:40:40     0          0       20
2017-10-15    13:40:50     0          0       10
2017-10-16    06:20:30     10         0       10
2017-10-16    06:20:40     70         0       10
2017-10-16    06:20:50     20         100     80
   .             .         .          .       .
   .             .         .          .       .
```

and there is more rows.(more than ten thousands)
You may notice that there is some **time gaps between 10/15 and 10/16.**
**I'd like to sum all three Axis values by minute.**
What I expect is this structure:

```
  Date         Time       Axis1     Axis2    Axis3
   .             .         .          .       .
   .             .         .          .       .
2017-10-15    13:40:00     120        20      230
2017-10-16    06:20:00     100        100     100
2017-10-16    06:21:00     ?          ?       ?
   .             .         .          .       .
   .             .         .          .       .
```

I tried to use groupby, resample and pd.Grouper, But it does not work for me.
The main problem is that **time index is not start from 13:40:00, but start from 00:00:00** after I put time as an index and **use groupby('Date') and resample('1Min').sum()**.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use `between_time` after `resample` operation to filter out the time-range you don't want.

Comment: Could you show an example??

Comment: For example if you only need the data between 06:20 and 13:40 for every day, you can do `df = df.between_time('06:20:00','13:40:00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

df.groupby(df.index.floor('T')).sum()
```

Output:

```
                     Axis1  Axis2  Axis3
2017-10-15 13:40:00    120     20    230
2017-10-16 06:20:00    100    100    100
```

**Note:**  Use `format` parmeter in `pd.to_datetime` to help with efficiency.  Use `floor` to avoid resampling or grouping over missing times.

Comment: It seems not work for me :( 
The result is same as I did. 
First row looks like this : 2017-10-15 00:00:00

Comment: Actually it does work in this case, but for some reasons, it's not working on my data.

Comment: I think that it appears from 00:00:00 because of groupby.  I'd like to keep the order. Could you give me an advise??

Comment: Can you more carefully examine your input data?  For example file one of the groups that has 00:00:00, query your input data for minimum time on that day.